# How would gravity work in this alternate universe?

Tags: physics, hard-science, orbital-mechanics

In my universe, gravity varies with the inverse of the distance (instead of the inverse square of the distance). I already know that this means that all circular orbits around the same object will have the same speed, and no true escape trajectories can exist, but there are some facts that I can't figure out about how the universe will work.

What shape will non-circular orbits take (or do they not exist)? Also, is there anything else weird about gravity in this universe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/37285/627. There won't be any stable closed orbits.

Comment: I'd say this is not an exact duplicate since that one only talks about orbits and it omits "special cases" which I care about.

Comment: Also, that post only cares about periodic orbits, while mine allows orbits that become chaotic messes but don't fall back down to the parent body.

Comment: The discussions I've seen about about linear inverse gravity, the subject of your question, suggests all orbits decay and fall on the parent body. This will include chaotic orbits. You will need to research some obscure corners of physics to find the answer.

Comment: Also note that such a law would *not* obey the conservation of energy.

Comment: How would it not obey conservation of energy? It just changes the formula for gravitational potential energy.

Comment: @CortAmmon It would. The vectorfield 1/r has no curl.

Comment: @JarredAllen Your'e right.  I wrote that one and then I had to ponder.  Now you've got me trying to remember what the issue was, because I know I've discussed this before.  Was it that you can't have extended bodies because the force of gravity no longer operates the same on an extended body vs. the collection of points that make up that body?  There was definitely something along those lines that got really ugly if your 1/r^n exponent was not equal to the number of dimensions minus 1.

Comment: Someone is certainly cutting corners on creating their universe!

Answer (score 8):

In order to generate an elliptical orbit, you need to have a force which is equal to the required centripetal force:

$$F=m\frac{v^2}{r}\rightarrow a=\frac{v^2}{r}$$

According to [Bertrand's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_theorem), this can only be solved with a potential for an inverse square force, or a radial harmonic oscillator potential.

So we cannot attain a circular orbit, is that a problem? No.

I generated a system for our sun, Earth, and moon, dependent on a linear inverse force. What we find is that we need to rescale the Gravitational constant to the negative 22nd order. (For clarity's sake I avoided using astronomical units).

So if we set $G = 6.6740831\times10^{-22}$ we find the following orbit patterns:

[image]
[image]

We can further decrease the orbital eccentricity when $G \rightarrow 4\times10^{-22}$

Note however, that in the long term, the eccentricity will always increase, even for optimal $G$, take the following radial Sol-Earth distance over 500y:

[image]

There are more problems though, for instance, would a star even form with this Gravity configuration?

Note that in this configuration, the acceleration of gravity due to Earth on its surface would be $0.000375m/s^2$ instead of $9.8m/s^2$
As the gravity drops off more slowly, but is also significantly more massive, a habitable planet would be much more massive, but such massive planets might also more easily form under these parameters.

And here is where things get really interesting, if we suppose that our planet has a mass of $m_{earth}=5.97237\times10^{28}$, four orders higher than that of the current Earth, gravity at the same radius would be $3.75m/s^2$, and we get the following 1000 year progression:

[image]

My suspicion is that the collapse happens 4 orders of magnitude slower, meaning you would have at least $10^5y$ of stable orbit, possible a million (1Ma).

If you could have a planet with a mass of order $O\left(29\right)$, then you might get a near-stable orbit over evolutionary time scales, however getting such a large concentration of Earth (oxyen, quartz, aluminium, lime, iron, magnesium) might be difficult to attain, except maybe in a late-stage galaxy.

I do think the peculiar circumstances would make the formation of large planets more likely as distance is less of a factor for matter to come together. Consequently we would expect fewer planets, but of higher average mass. However, it is also possible this situation would lead to more uniformity in mass distributions.
You would have to run some galaxy wide gravity calculations for that one, and recalculate the result of the background radiation. These are things beyond my scope.

Comment: What program did you use to generate your graphics? Can you link to code, on github maybe?

Comment: @kingledion I used my own `Mathematica` code. I recognize it's handier to have this in `Python` for sharing, but I adapted this from code I still had for a regular n-body solution. I'm no where near as good with `Python` yet as I am with `Mathematica`.

Comment: Well, good work. I was working on this in Python last night and wanted to plagiarize. :)

Comment: @kingledion I can say is I used `NDSolve[]`, which would be roughly equivalen to `odeint()` for Python, except it's much more straight forward on `Mathematica`.
If you do figure this out on Python I'd be interested to know if you can come to the same solutions.

Comment: On your second graph, is that a stable point around 1.5e10, or is that an artifact?

Comment: @CortAmmon That's an artefact, the plot is highly oscillatory and I didn't take enough plot points apparently.

Comment: When you say that the eccentricity will always increase, is this based on the simulations you ran or a mathematical proof.  If it's based on the simulations, it's important to recognize that these simulations can get an accumulation of errors over a large number of time steps and so make orbits look less stable than they really are.  For instance when I ran simulations of a two body system using the inverse square law with large time step increments the planet would appear to move further from its star even though that doesn't really happen using the inverse square law for newtonian mechanics.